# Commit vs CommitRetaining

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

I have made a Delphi application, which inserts a row into Firebird database.
There was a problem with a query which a solved via CommitRetaining, but I read that it is not right thing to use, because it may affect the server being more slow. Strange thing happens when I use Commit only, query runs ok, but when I want to see if the row is inserted, Retainingit isn't. It only gets inserted on application terminate. But when using CommitRetaining, the row is inserted instantly.

What may cause the problem?
EDIT: Code using CommitRetaining

```
             adqPom := TADQuery.Create(nil);
             adqPom.Connection := form1.ADOConnection1;
             adTransakcija := TADTransaction.Create(nil);
             adTransakcija.Connection:=form1.ADOConnection1;
             adqPom.Transaction:=adTransakcija;
             adTransakcija.StartTransaction;
             try
               with adqPom do
               begin
                 close;
                 sql.Clear;
                 sql.Add('insert into uplate(sifra,b_prijema,magacin,datum,iznos,b_uplate,b_izvoda,banka,godina,tr_rac,datum_dokument)');
                 sql.Add('values(:S,:BP,:M,:D,:I,:BU,:BI,:B,:G,:TR,:DD)');
                 ParamByName('S').Value := strtoint(edit1.Text);
                 if Form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['A1'] = 3 then
                     edit3.Text := '99999';
                 ParamByName('BP').Value := edit3.Text;
                 ParamByName('M').Value := edit2.Text;
                 ParamByName('D').Value := strtodate(edit4.Text);
                 ParamByName('I').Value := StrToFloat(edit5.Text);
                 ParamByName('BU').Value := Br_Uplate+1;
                 ParamByName('BI').Value := strtoint(Edit6.Text);
                 ParamByName('B').Value := Edit8.Text;
                 ParamByName('G').Value := 2006;
                 if Form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['A1'] = 3 then
                   ParamByName('TR').Value:= form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['B_PRIJEMA']
                 else
                   ParamByName('TR').Value:= Form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['B_DOST'];
                 ParamByName('DD').Value:=StrToDate(edit9.Text);
                 ExecSQL;
               end;
               adTransakcija.CommitRetaining;
             except
               adTransakcija.RollbackRetaining;
               raise;
             end;
             FreeAndNil(adTransakcija);
             FreeAndNil(adqPom);
```

EDIT: Code using Commit (actually property of a query is set to autocommit)

```
               adqPom := TADQuery.Create(nil);
               adqPom.Connection := form1.ADOConnection1;
               with adqPom do
               begin
                 close;
                 sql.Clear;
                 sql.Add('insert into uplate(sifra,b_prijema,magacin,datum,iznos,b_uplate,b_izvoda,banka,godina,tr_rac,datum_dokument)');
                 sql.Add('values(:S,:BP,:M,:D,:I,:BU,:BI,:B,:G,:TR,:DD)');
                 ParamByName('S').Value := strtoint(edit1.Text);
                 if Form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['A1'] = 3 then
                     edit3.Text := '99999';
                 ParamByName('BP').Value := edit3.Text;
                 ParamByName('M').Value := edit2.Text;
                 ParamByName('D').Value := strtodate(edit4.Text);
                 ParamByName('I').Value := StrToFloat(edit5.Text);
                 ParamByName('BU').Value := Br_Uplate+1;
                 ParamByName('BI').Value := strtoint(Edit6.Text);
                 ParamByName('B').Value := Edit8.Text;
                 ParamByName('G').Value := 2006;
                 if Form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['A1'] = 3 then
                   ParamByName('TR').Value:= form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['B_PRIJEMA']
                 else
                   ParamByName('TR').Value:= Form15.adoqDostavn.FieldValues['B_DOST'];
                 ParamByName('DD').Value:=StrToDate(edit9.Text);
                 ExecSQL;
               end;
               FreeAndNil(adqPom);
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but the only difference I know is that CommitRetaining should just keep the transaction in active state. Where did you read that CommitRetaining is not a good practice?
Try reactivating the transaction after a "normal" Commit, you should find the rows you've inserted.

Comment: @ExDev commit retaining **can** be problematic because the transaction gap increases if the transaction is alive for too long, which inhibits garbage collection, which can lead to longer record version chains that need to be scanned, which then can lead to worse performance.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are querying from a transaction that was started before the record was inserted. You need to show the code that exhibits this problem.

Comment: Sure, code posted.

Comment: Have you tried using an explicit commit instead of relying on auto commit, because my guess (I don't know Delphi) would be that your 'commit' code  never triggers an actual commit.

Comment: I have made 3 versions and looks like that in third one (in which you mentioned to implement explicit commit) is running just like first one (with CommitRetaining), it inserts row instantly which is what I was looking for.
Now, the biggest problem is to implement all that code where I used auto-commit mode of a query to explicit commit, it could take days. But, it should be more stable, right?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - additionally, BLOB id's start to leak - they are only freed on transaction committing. That means, even transactions declared read-only, if they are long-live, tend to create more and more database objects, if text blobs are used in expressions.

Comment: @Arioch'The You can also explicitly close blobs.

Comment: When working with FB API directly. Or when working with thin FB-only library. However when working with Delphi where tables objects infrastructure was coded 20 years ago for BDE ISAM... There just is no such concept as blob, that is a specific subclass of field, and how the types mapping works is version specific implementation detail.... There is no exposed blob id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commit free the transaction environment and CommitRetaining is a Commit that not free the transaction environment (cursors still open). You can use CommitRetaining in a process but at the end you must use Commit to release the memory.

Usually CommitRetainning is used to optimize a process (that include a big number of Begin/Commit), but at the end of you must this process use Commit to clear memory.